# Problems with res folder and R.java

Tags: android, r.java-file

I'm doing Tutorials and I'm on section about images. It says to put them into the folder res/drawable. But I don't have that folder, I have three instead: `res/drawable-hdpi`, r`es/drawable-ldpi` and `res/drawable-mdpi`. So whats the difference between them?

Im using [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) tutorial.

One of the steps is:

> Create a strings.xml file in
>   res/values/ and edit the file to look
>   like

There already is  `strings.xml`, combined with the above, telling me to use res/drawable, are these tutorials out of date?

This tutorial has code like:

```
R.id.spinner
R.array.planets_array
```

R.layout is just simple enum. Uses the main.xml in the layout folder. But where are `R.id` and `R.array` to come from. Because it is coming up in eclipse saying it doesn't know what they are. `R.java` gets updated automatically, so can someone tell me from reading that tutorial where id gets added to R? It says that

> The R.array.planets_array ID
>   references the string-array defined
>   above

Only it doesn't work. I doubt it makes a difference that i didn't make strings.xml since it's the same filename in the same location. But since R.java is meant to be updated automatically I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Those are for the different screen resolutions for the range of devices that are out there. Read about [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on the Android dev site.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know where the R stuff comes from.

The `R.java` file is a generated file which contains some kind of pointers to a resource in your application. It is a simple integer actually which uniquely identifies the resource in the internal resource management system of Android.

`R.string` identifiers are generated from resources XML files like this one for example.

```
<resources>
    <string name="test">This is a test string.</string>
</resources>
```

`R.array` identifiers from string array XML files.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="days_of_week">
        <item>Monday</item>
        <item>Tuesday</item>
        <item>Wednesday</item>
        <item>Thursday</item>
        <item>Friday</item>
        <item>Saturday</item>
        <item>Sunday</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

You can access that array using its identifier `R.id.days_of_week` now.

`R.id` identifiers are a bit special.

They are generated in two ways. The first one is when you define a `View` in your XML layout file using the `@+id/...` syntax. Note the `+` sign.

The other way is to define them in resource XML files like strings for example.

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="first" />
    <item type="id" name="second" />
</resources>
```

You'd then just use them in a layout XML file like this `@id/first`. Note that there is **no** `+` sign anymore as you reference it, before you were declaring it.

In code you then use it like this, `R.id.first`.

There are a lot of other resources. I'd like to point you to the [Application Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html) article and also make sure to checkout the [Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) sub-article.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the folder, just create it. It is basically the fallback for the case that you don't have a resource in a more specific folder like res/drawable-hdpi

The *-xx folders allow you to provide more specific drawables (images) for various screen resolutions.

The same principle applies to values/ and values-xx/ where xx is a country code ; the xx versions allow you to have translations for UI messages.